# Bound on derivative implies bound on function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If $u'(t) \leq u(t)$ for all $t$, does this imply that $u(t) \leq u_0e^t$ for all $t$?

I'm not sure how to prove this. I know that, if the inequality is tight (i.e. "worst case"), we get $u(t) = u_0e^t$ as a solution. However, I can imagine that $u$ starts off larger than an exponential (i.e., violates our conclusion for some $t$) but has a smaller derivative than an exponential (i.e. matches our hypothesis) for all $t$. I think it comes down to using the fact that the derivative is bounded by the function itself, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Take a look at Gronwall's inequality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality

Comment: If "for all $t$" means "$t \in \mathbb{R}$" and $u_0$ means $u(0)$ this is wrong. Take $u(t)=1$ $(t \in \mathbb{R})$. You should specify what "for all $t$" means and how $u_0$ is connected to $u$.